# How to add categorical labels to a new column in R

Tags: r

sorry I'm still a newb in R and am having difficulties adding my new column ("chicken") below to my data=c, separated by: black (starting cell 34453 to 6015) and white (starting from cell 1 to 34452). Any help would be great appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
c["chicken"] <- NA
c$chicken[c(1:34452)] = 'white'
c$chicken[c(34453:6015)] = 'black'
```

Comment: You should not call your variable `c` as it is the concatenate function. Rename the variable and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, accounting for the likely typo:

```
vector.length <- nrow(c)
c$chicken <- NA
c$chicken[1:34452] = 'white'
c$chicken[34453:vector.length] = 'black'
```

As a general resource for questions like this one, I would recommend [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot about declaring factor variables. Your edits worked perfectly. Now, I can start mapping my chicken spatial data :)

Answer (score 0):

There's some ambiguity in your question, so I'm going to answer what I *think* is your question.

I believe your issue is that if you have a factor (i.e. the variable chicken), you cannot simply add a new level of the factor without modifying the variable. To illustrate this, trying running this and see the error reported by R:

`exampleData <- data.frame(chicken = rep('black', 4) )
 exampleData                          #Examine what we created
 exampleData$chicken[3:4] <- 'white'  #attempting to add a new level not defined yet`

To add a new level to a factor, simply use the `levels` function:

`levels(exampleData$chicken) <- c('black', 'white')
 exampleData$chicken[3:4] <- 'white'
 exampleData                           #Now that the level has been added, works fine!`

Alternatively, you can keep your variable as a character, rather than a factor, and then you can add whatever variable you want without having to worry about levels. This is a two edged sword though: it won't catch typos, as a factor would! See below.

`exampleData <- data.frame(chicken = rep('black', 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 exampleData$chicken[3] <- 'white'    #no need to relevel since it's not a factor
 exampleData$chicken[4] <- 'whiet'    #but doesn't catch typo, so there are now
                                      #3 unique values of chicken!`